# Google Vision API applied to identifying a javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-api, ocr, google-vision

I am trying to create an application that read an image containing a simple Javascript code -- ex: a `const a = 123; console.log(a);` -- and execute this code afterwards.

For that, I am trying to use Google Vision API. My main problem so far is that some special characters (`=`, `=>`, `;`) are not being recognized correctly.

Some examples:

`const a = 123` is converted to `const a -123`

`const a = '123'` is converted to `const a 123`

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829583/special-characters-which-are-identified-as-individual-word-in-google-vision-ocr), and it seems that I can insert some special chars to be recognized, but I do not know where.

Is there a way to improve the recognition for this context?

Comment: Given the input and output you can try to create logic which inserts `=` following variable identifier.

Comment: @guest271314 Those are some few examples. Other cases are `{` and `}`. I would not like to try all possible cases and create a logic for each one. Maybe there is a way of reading all chars and do not try to make any sense for the words. That way keep all originals chars. WDYT?

Comment: Would initially create logic for all cases. One or more "models" can be "trained", see https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples; fuzzy-logic could also be utilized.